# Django: Model inheritance from abstract models based on condition

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my model there is an option field `recursion_period`:

```
class RecurringMeeting(models.Model):
    RECURSION_OPTIONS = (
        ('daily', 'Daily'),
        ('weekly', 'Weekly'),
    )

    recursion_period = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=RECURSION_OPTIONS)
```

Based on the value of the `recursion_period` value I would like to inherit fields from either the `DailyMeeting` or the `WeeklyMeeting` abstract models:

```
class DailyMeeting(models.Model):
    # some fields here

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

and

```
class WeeklyMeeting(models.Model):
    # some other fields here

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Would it be possible to choose which model to inherit based on the value of the `recursion_period` field?

Comment: No, that is not possible. Why do you need inheritance? It seems like [generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) would be more suitable.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is not possible. I will try to find another solution, possibly using generic relations.